# gradle multi-project: ordering / dependencies

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

i have a multi-project build that includes many sub projects.

```
include ':common'
project( ':common' ).projectDir = new File( rootDir, 'android-common/common' )

include ':setup'
project( ':setup' ).projectDir = new File( rootDir, 'android-setup/setup' )
...
```

i'd like to add ordering (or dependencies) between them, at the master project level. in the above example, i want `common` to always build before `setup`. it *seems like* i want do something like get a reference to `setup:compile` (or whatever the build task is named) and add an additional dependency. something like,

```
tasks[':setup'].dependsOn += tasks[':common:install']
```

obviously that doesn't work. is this possible?

EDIT: a little more detail. the result of `:common` is to install a maven artifact, which is then used by `:setup`. so, the dependency between them is soft. however, in our typical dev cycle we still want to build `:common` first.

Answer (score 2):

it sounds to me like you want to use project dependencies

```
project(':setup') {
   dependencies {
     compile project(':common')
   }
}
```

EDIT: it seems that you just want to declare cross-project task dependencies in your parent build.gradle.

```
tasks.getByPath(":setup:compile").dependsOn(":common:install")
```

Note that this will cause the setup project to be evaluated/configured at that point. If this causes problems for some reason, you might want to use an evaluation listener

```
project("setup").afterEvaluate { setup -> setup.compile.dependsOn ":common:install }
```

Further note that if you want to build the setup project independently in this structure you will have to use the -u command line option.

Comment: the problem is that setup now depends on common via a maven repo dependency, and i can't change that. any change has to be done at the master project level. setup is in a different git repo than common. the structure is we have many repos with "soft" dependencies through maven repos, but we'd like to develop on them with a single gradle project.

Comment: Can you explain why you have to use a maven dependency? Using a project dependency should still generate the correct dependency meta data when you publish.

Comment: because each of the repos need to build independently.

Comment: So you want to publish a new :common artifact to maven every time you build :setup?

Comment: yes, that is correct. i just want to order the execution of subproject builds. we made a decision at some point that there should be no hard dependencies between our repos, but then we are faced with the reality of day to day development.